# How to hide ChromeOS Coreboot on startup after installing Kali Linux

Tags: chromebook

I have an HP x360 and I have installed Kali linux via TianoCore and I originally was using MrChromeBox but everytime I restart the chromebook it shows the Recovery screen. Is there a way to set the chromebook to load straight to TianoCore as the bootloader?

Comment: via TianoCore   --  What is this?   I get Kali from the Kali site and install it that way. Kali sets up Grub as it installs.

Comment: TianoCore is what Kali runs on for uefi. Chromebooks use coreboot bootloader for ChromeOS and to get another bootloader mr.chromebox installs TianoCore so that when installing it that coreboot won't stop you from booting to the drive. Coreboot detects if it is ChromeOS or not

Comment: I don't know then. I use a Windows machine

Comment: I do as well, this is a learning curve for me